# Adding dependencies to a package

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, add-dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*Does the `catkin_make` process automatically download packages identified as dependencies ???*

I have a package which makes use of the [rosbridge](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_server) package.

I defined the find_package section of my CMakeLists.txt like so :

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rosbridge_server
  rospy
)
```

And I added the following lines to my package.xml :

```
  <build_export_depend>rosbridge_server</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>rosbridge_server</exec_depend>
```

However, I get the following when I execute *catkin_make* :

```
.
.
.
-- Could NOT find rosbridge_server (missing: rosbridge_server_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'rosbridge_server'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rosbridge_server"
  with any of the following names:

    rosbridge_serverConfig.cmake
    rosbridge_server-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rosbridge_server" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "rosbridge_server_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "rosbridge_server" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sweepbot/Sweeper/sweepbot_test2/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sisko/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/sisko/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I found [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/9177/adding-a-dependency-after-roscreate-pkg/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20add%20a,%3D%22rospy%22%20%2F%3E%20.) question but it's answer is out of date.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376856/adding-dependencies-to-a-package/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2021-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-23**:
Please do not ask multiple questions in a single post.

That's not how this site works. It's a Q&A site, which works best with a 1-to-1 ratio of questions to answers. Similar to how StackExchange et al. work.

It'd be best if you edit your current question and decide *which* of your questions you want to keep in this one.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-23**:
I would also suggest to see whether #q252478 demystifies the how-to-build-packages-from-sources question.

The fact they are "your own" packages, does not change the workflow (except of course you may not need to `git clone` them first).

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-04-23**:
Hello @gvdhoom. There seems to be a misunderstanding. My question may have multiple facets to it but they are all related to the same issue of adding dependencies to ros packages. I merely added more information from different perspectives.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-23**:\

> Also, when running `catkin_create_pkg` and adding dependencies as the package is being created, are the dependencies simply the name of the package OR the the correct dependency name found somewhere else ?

this is a different question than "does catkin download dependencies" and should be asked in a separate post.

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-04-23**:
Thank you @gvdboom: The link you provided referred to `rosdep` which does exactly what I needed and though *catkin_make* might.
If you care to provided your input as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To give this an answer:

> Does the `catkin_make` process automatically download packages identified as dependencies ???

No.

`catkin_make` is only responsible for *building* your workspace, it does not download anything.

In fact, `catkin_make` does not even directly build your workspace. It relies on tools like CMake to do that.

Catkin's main responsibility is to figure out in *which order* your packages should be built, as dependencies must be built before dependents.

The tool which is responsible for gathering the dependencies of your ROS packages is [rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep). It reads that information from all the `package.xml` files (ie: the manifests) in your workspace, computes which dependencies are missing from your workspace (if you specify the `--ignore-src` option) and then instructs *other tools* to actually install your dependencies (in most cases: `apt` and `pip`).

Summarising: `catkin_make` does not download nor install dependencies of your packages. `rosdep` is the tool which is supposed to do that.

See #q215059 for a more in-depth discussion on `rosdep`, and refer to #q217475 on *why* you need to duplicate (some of the) dependency information in both `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1